# WordPress Failing to add custom post type to query using pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm failing to add a custom post type to the query using pre_get_posts. I've created my own theme and integrated this plugin (https://github.com/Develop-With-WP/wp-job-listing).

How do I now add this new post_type 'job' to my query? I tried this:

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'job' ) );
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
```

I am able to check the post_type but when I put [shortcode_debug] in the editors' post and call /general/first-blog/ .

But when I'm calling /job/sales/ it still doesn't render anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->query_vars[ 'post_type' ] = [ 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'job' ];    
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
```

Comment: Still no result. I've put this in wp-job-cpt.php of https://github.com/Develop-With-WP/wp-job-listing . Is this correct way to do it?

Comment: I think it should work if put in that file. But do try to put it in your theme's functions.php just to test

Comment: Still not. The weird thing is I can't even echo anything (like $post_type = 'Test'; echo $post_type;) to /job/sales/ . Also if I put something in the editor it's not there. For /general/first-blog/ it's there ...

Comment: I have a similar snippet, as the one from my answer, working great on a client's live site. I think it should work, unless you've a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Now it's working. The issue was also that the function cfs_load_templates() caused the error when returning get_page_template(); I took get_page_template(); out and now its working ..

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt' );
function get_posts_plus_cpt( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {        
      $query->set( 'post_type', 'job' );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, no result. As mentioned below ... the weird thing is I can't even echo anything (like $post_type = 'Test'; echo $post_type;) to /job/sales/ . Also if I put something in the editor it's not there. For /general/first-blog/ it's there ...

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_plus_cpt' );

function get_posts_plus_cpt( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {        
       $query->set( 'post_type', 'job' );
    }
    return $query;
}
```